# Embedding script engine and iOS or Android store approval or rejecting

Tags: google-play, app-store

If an app embeds a script engine, even though it can run correctly in iOS or Android deployment install, and it executes no downloaded native code, then may be the app be rejected by iOS Appstore staff or Android Google Play staff?

For example, a game app which embeds a Javascript-like script runtime engine and it downloads some script code from the game server and execute as interpreter language. It may be used for user interface interaction in game play.

Answer (score 0):

This question will probably get closed for being off-topic for StackOverflow. Any answer you get on StackOverflow will be primarily opinion based.

You should go to the actual source for this. For Google Play, it is the [Google Play policy centre](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/). This says "Apps or SDKs that download executable code, such as dex files or native code, from a source other than Google Play."

Dynamic code is a major feature of malware, and also a large security risk, so doing this in your design is probably a bad idea if you want to get approved by the various App stores.